# jQuery Organic Tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs

I'm using the organic tabs plugin - http://css-tricks.com/4530-organic-tabs/ -  and need a bit of help.

Depending on the class on the body tag, I wish to switch between two lists  - for example, if a user is looking at a sail boat, I'd like the tabs to switch to the 'panel2' by default.

Likewise, if they are looking at a power boat, then I'd like the tab to be on 'panel1' by default.

The HTML is

```
<div id="sailOrPower">  
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-one"><a href="#panel1" class="current">Top Power</a></li>
        <li class="nav-two"><a href="#panel2">Top Sail</a></li>   
    </ul>
    <div class="listWrap">
        <ul id="panel1">
            <li><a href="#">Power boat 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Power boat 1</a></li>  
        </ul>    
        <ul id="panel2" class="hide">
            <li><a href="#">Sail boat 1</a></li>    
            <li><a href="#">Sail boat 1</a></li>    
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the default function I have is

```
$(function () {
$("#sailOrPower").organicTabs({
"speed": 0
});
});
```

This obviously needs to change.

I'm still learning jQuery and so am a little unsure of the best way to approach this is, so any tips would be great. The method I'm thinking is that jQuery needs to...

1. Find the class on the body - sail or power
2. Find the current list and see which list is displaying - panel1 or panel2
3. Check to see if the current list matches the class on the body
4. If it does match, do nothing?
5. If it doesn't match then switch to display the correct list - I guess this would be done by adding/removing the class 'hide' that is currently on panel 2?

There are times when the body won't have a sail OR power class at all and so in those circumstances, the tabs can just behave as normal.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

*UPDATED********

Ok so have been playing around today and my (admittedly very clumsy way of writing jQuery) seems to do MOST of what I need it to HOWEVER... there is something I'm a little stuck on. If the user clicks the Power tab whilst on the Sail page, the tab will switch BUT the list won't display as it's being told to be hidden in the previous function - anyhow, I'm having with that part see below... Any ideas?

```
$(function() {
    var $body = $('body');

    if ($body.is('.sailPage')) {
        $('#sailOrPower ul.nav li.nav-one a').removeClass('current');
        $('#sailOrPower ul.nav li.nav-two a').addClass('current');
        $('#sailOrPower .listWrap ul#panel1').addClass('hide');
        $('#sailOrPower .listWrap ul#panel2').css('display', 'block');
    }
else if ('#sailOrPower ul.nav li.nav-one a').hasClass('current')  {
    $('#sailOrPower .listWrap ul#panel1').removeClass('hide')
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry - added comment by phone - was a bit difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good solution because if you have lots of tabs you have to write this check for every tab, but if you have only two it may be a quick solution.

```
$(function() {
  if($('.sail').size() > 0) {
    $('#sailOrPower .listWrap ul')
      .removeClass('hide')
      .filter('#panel2')
      .addClass('hide');
  }
  if($('.power').size() > 0) {
    $('#sailOrPower .listWrap ul')
      .removeClass('hide')
      .filter('#panel1')
      .addClass('hide');
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, yes there will only ever be two tabs so in theory your solution would work, however it doesn't seem to :( I also need to be able to remove/add the class of 'current' on the ul.nav to the appropriate tab (initially forgot about this)